# Where is search on Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: 11.10, software-center, search

It seems to have disappeared.   The menu Edit/Search doesn't work, either.

[image]

I've filed a [launchpad bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/897387).

Comment: If you've filed a bug report then there's probably no need to post it here.

Comment: Please refrain from posting bugs as they are considered [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions). Thanks!

Comment: What theme are you using? I notice that you have menus for File Edit View and Help as part of the Window which on my Unity User Interface are in the top panel. Perhaps the changes that you have made to the User Interface have caused this.

Comment: I tried several themes to see if that was the problem.  No search in any of the themes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gary Lasker from Canoical contacted me through launchpad.  He asked me to run Ubuntu Software Center from a terminal using the command line.

`⋯$ software-center`

I did that and the search box is back.  There were no updates in the interim so it possibly was a one time thing (so far).

Thanks to Gary for getting back to me quickly!

Answer (score 14):

### Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

The Search textbox is hidden by default, **it is automatically displayed when typing.**

Comment: Bad UI design .

Comment: for f sake this is idiotic

Comment: I agree, it is not an intuitive UX.

Comment: You're right. Search bar appears as I start typing.

Comment: Wow, thanks for posting this! Honestly, I don't think it's intuitive at all.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this answer is just silly, but it is not just the case that the window is not big enough to show the Search textbox? If i resize my window to that size, the Search disappears because there's no space to it be shown.

Comment: That is not the case on my 11.10 system. There is a limit to how narrow we can make the window and it still has the search panel.

Comment: I have 11.10 too (Ambiance theme) and when i resize it to the minimum size allowed, the Search bar dissapears: http://goo.gl/wmva2

Comment: I didn't change it from it's default size when it opened, pretty much filled the small laptop screen.

Comment: @Cams this is a usability failure on Ubuntu's side. Don't feel stupid.